# Should I mention that I will be opting for the non-thesis option in my statement of purpose?

Tags: application, statement-of-purpose

I am planning to apply for Master's in Electrical and Computer Engineering. I have prepared most of the application requirements (GRE,TOEFL,transcripts,LORs,Resume). The only thing left is my SOP. I intend to take up the non-thesis (project option) in my final semester. Should I mention this in my SOP?
If yes, How do I go about stating this?

Comment: I don't see a need to state this.  Who wants to read a negative?  Focus on the positive.  Plus, you never know, you might change your mind.

Comment: @aparente001 How do I go about? I dont have much research experience. But I have 2 years of related work experience

Comment: Please clarify what you asked in the comment.  (The answer to the Question is, don't mention your lack of interest in writing a thesis when you write your SOP.)  What do you want to know how to go about doing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a prior commenter noted, you can be silent on the issue without prejudice from the admissions officer.  In fact, it's quite common for graduate students not to make the thesis/no thesis decision until they have a semester or a couple of quarters behind them.  The decision to write a thesis is often the product of one's evolution during graduate work.  For example, if you were to decide that you want to pursue a doctorate, then writing a thesis has distinct advantages, the most important of which is that it prepares you for writing a dissertation.  Conversely, if you want the broadest knowledge and lab experience, course work is preferable.